# Como mudar configurações CSS de todas as DIVs com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Preciso trocar a cor do `background`, a cor dos textos e dos *links* de todas as DIVs de um *site*.
Consegui fazer isso em JavaScript com o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function altoContraste() {
        var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        var links = geral.getElementsByTagName("a");


    for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
         divs[i].style.background= '#000';
         divs[i].style.color= '#FFF';

    }
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
         links[i].style.color = '#FF0';
    }


}
</script>
```

Porém preciso fazer isso utilizando jQuery, não entendo jQuery, mas pesquisei em alguns lugares como fazer e cheguei no seguinte código:

```
<script>
$(".altoContrase").click( 
$("div").each(function() {
$(this).css({
'background': '#000', 'color': '#FFF'
})
});
</script>
```

Por que ele não está funcionando? O que eu devo fazer pra conseguir fazer isso?
Fora que nesse código jQuery não consigo mudar a cor dos *links*.

Comment: Se consegue fazer com javascript puro qual é a ideia de fazer em jQuery? perda de tempo. Ou tem alguma coisa que não está a funcionar?

Comment: Esse codigo jQuery está correto? (i.e. é o mesmo código que tem na sua página? está faltando um parêntese aí, e a forma de chamar o `click` é passando uma função - igual você fez com o `each`)

Comment: A ideia de fazer em jquery é porque com o javascript tá dando problema em alterar algumas coisas em tabelas.

Comment: jQuery é JavaScript. Se explicar o problema que tem em javascript vai ser uma pergunta mais interssante.

Comment: Estou mexendo ainda, não consegui fazer nada com o jquery.Então eu devo fazer : $(".altoContrase").click( function() {
e dps continuar do mesmo jeito que estava ?

Comment: @Sergio com o código javascript eu não consigo mudar as configurações das tabelas. Fazendo:
 var tabelas= geral.getElementsByTagName("table");
 for (var i = 0; i < tabelas.length; i++) {
         tabelas[i].style.background= '#000';
         tabelas[i].style.color= '#FFF';
    }

não funciona, a tabela não muda.
Tentei também fazer o mesmo mas com TR mas tbm não funcionou

Comment: @LucasVilela Acho melhor abrir uma pergunta separada pra isso, já que não tem nada a ver com a pergunta atual. A propósito, eu não vejo problema algum em se usar jQuery mesmo quando se consegue fazer em JavaScript puro, pois o código jQuery é geralmente mais conciso. Mas se você tem uma solução pronta, de fato é mais negócio resolver os problemas dela do que introduzir uma framework pesada só para isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assim:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.altoContraste').click(function(){
      $('div').css('background-color', '#000');
      $('div').css('color', '#FFF');
      $('a').css('color', '#FF0');
   });
});
</script>
```

Lembre-se que no seu html deve haver algum botão ou tag que possua a classe altoContraste

Comment: Funcionou, vlw!
Pra eu por os links em amarelo como eu faço ?

Comment: Resposta atualizada

Comment: Muito obrigado!